# 500 Server Error when serving PHP using Nginx

Tags: nginx, php, ubuntu-18.04

Am using ubuntu 18.04, with nginx...
Nginx does not serve the php files.
**It gives a 500 error**

It serves html pages but not php

Am using php fpm, php 7.2.19

Pls help me with the code, I tried all methods possible, it still doesn't serve php pages

below is my sites-available page/code

```
##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/
# https://wiki.debian.org/Nginx/DirectoryStructure
#
# In most cases, administrators will remove this file from sites-enabled/ and
# leave it as reference inside of sites-available where it will continue to be
# updated by the nginx packaging team.
#
# This file will automatically load configuration files provided by other
# applications, such as Drupal or Wordpress. These applications will be made
# available underneath a path with that package name, such as /drupal8.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

        root /var/www/html/paystaple/public;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        #index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        index index.php

        server_name _;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
                #include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                include fastcgi.conf;
#
        #       # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        #       # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
#               fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #       deny all;
        #}
}

# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#       listen 80;
#       listen [::]:80;
#
#       server_name example.com;
#
#       root /var/www/example.com;
#       index index.html;
#
#       location / {
#               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#       }
#}
```

Comment: Doesn't look like anything is wrong with this config. Can you test it with a simple phpinfo page? Also enable php errors in php.ini and see if anything comes up.

Comment: @esoroka No error. Php info does not work

Comment: Check the error logs for nginx (usually /var/log/nginx/error.log ) and php-fpm (should be /var/log/php7.2-fpm.log)

Comment: @esoroka Here's the stacktrace for nginx error.log
https://pastebin.com/ThLNqcqu

Comment: As you can see from the error, it's not a server config problem. PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ErrorException: file_put_contents(/var/www/html/paystaple/storage/framework/views/d5f5f4ed65777fe3e1de0c50b38e7bf98e77ff76.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in . Check your filesystem permissions

Comment: so now what should i do

Comment: @esoroka what should i change it to